# Insert a photo from Base64 in RecyclerView

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm making a Recycler View with cells that each have a photo which should get converted from a Base64 string provided by the database. The problem is, I don't know how to set it up.

My user class:

```
class userProfileModel
    {
        public int userId { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string userPhotobase64 { get; set; }
        public Image userPhoto { get; set; }
```

My cell template for the Recycler:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_height="190dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Refractored.Controls.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_photo_in_interested_choice"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/photoplaceholder"
            app:civ_border_color="#FF0199"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username_text_in_interested_choice"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Nazwa użytkownika"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        

        
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/deny_in_interested_choice"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/accept_user_photo"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"/>

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/accept_in_interested_choice"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/deny_user_photo"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"/>
            
            
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I don't know how to reference the Image in the adapter. How could I do that?

The adapter:

```
namespace DatingAppLicencjat.Adapters
{
    class InterestedUsersAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        public event EventHandler<InterestedUsersAdapterClickEventArgs> ItemClick;
        public event EventHandler<InterestedUsersAdapterClickEventArgs> ItemLongClick;
        List<userProfileModel> userList;

        public InterestedUsersAdapter(List<userProfileModel> data)
        {
            userList = data;
        }

        // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {

            //Setup your layout here
            View itemView = null;


            itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.user_interested_selection_template, parent, false);

            var vh = new InterestedUsersAdapterViewHolder(itemView, OnClick, OnLongClick);
            return vh;
        }

        // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
        {
            var user = userList[position];

            // Replace the contents of the view with that element
            var holder = viewHolder as InterestedUsersAdapterViewHolder;
            holder.username_in_interested_choice.Text = user.username;
            
            //holder.TextView.Text = items[position];
        }

        public override int ItemCount => userList.Count;

        void OnClick(InterestedUsersAdapterClickEventArgs args) => ItemClick?.Invoke(this, args);
        void OnLongClick(InterestedUsersAdapterClickEventArgs args) => ItemLongClick?.Invoke(this, args);

    }

    public class InterestedUsersAdapterViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView username_in_interested_choice;
        public CircleImageView user_photo_in_interested_choice;
        public ImageView accept_user_in_interested_choice;
        public ImageView deny_user_in_interested_choice;


        public InterestedUsersAdapterViewHolder(View itemView, Action<InterestedUsersAdapterClickEventArgs> clickListener,
                            Action<InterestedUsersAdapterClickEventArgs> longClickListener) : base(itemView)
        {
            username_in_interested_choice = (TextView)itemView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.username_text_in_interested_choice);
            user_photo_in_interested_choice = (CircleImageView)itemView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.user_photo_in_interested_choice);
            accept_user_in_interested_choice = (ImageView)itemView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.accept_in_interested_choice);
            deny_user_in_interested_choice = (ImageView)itemView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.deny_in_interested_choice);
            itemView.Click += (sender, e) => clickListener(new InterestedUsersAdapterClickEventArgs { View = itemView, Position = AdapterPosition });
            itemView.LongClick += (sender, e) => longClickListener(new InterestedUsersAdapterClickEventArgs { View = itemView, Position = AdapterPosition });
        }
    }

    public class InterestedUsersAdapterClickEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public View View { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the Get/Set.  I just did first step of going from/to base64string to string. You need to actually convert to an image.

```
    class userProfileModel
    {
        public int userId { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string userPhotobase64 { get; set; }
        private Image _userPhoto { get; set; }
        public string userPhoto
        {
            get { return Convert.ToBase64String(_userPhoto); }
            set { userPhoto = Convert.FromBase64String(value); }
        }
    }
```